# Why am I getting a delay when I'm using scroll() in jquery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using some simple code to have an item appear when the page is scrolled to a certain point. The code technically works but it's highly delayed. I had the code `console.log` some debug values (the scroll position). I found that the if statement didn't run until after the scrolling had stopped (or when I saw the console.log "catch up"):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 350) {
        $('#logo').animate({'opacity':'1'});
    } else {
        $('#logo').animate({'opacity':'0'});
    }
});
```

here is a jsfiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/nzcxwdmx/1/

You'll notice, if you wait long enough the words "logo here" will show up. the further you scroll past 350, the longer it will take.

Comment: Default value of animation is duration (default: 400). Try to play with default values.

Answer (score 0):

you are using defaul animate time value instade of it use requred time value

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wishall/nzcxwdmx/2/)

Example code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var spos = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#scroll').text(spos);
    if(spos >= 350) {
        $('#logo').animate({'opacity':'1'},200);
    } else {
        $('#logo').animate({'opacity':'0'},200);
    }
});
```

Comment: it's not the timing of the animation that's the issue. Once you scroll past 350 it takes a long time for the animation to start. I need it to show as soon as it reaches 351 or more and hide when it's at 350 or less. Again, it does hide and show at these values however, it just takes too long to get to that point.